# Left outer join where right hand table has multiple matching rows

Tags: sql

If I have 2 tables A and B with one column and we have values like:

```
A  
col1  
1
```

```
B  
col1  
1  
1  
1  
2
```

When I do

```
select *
from A
left join B on A.col1 = B.col1
```

should I get one row (corresponding to the record in A) or 3 rows (corresponding to 3 matching records in B)? Or will it give an error?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: Or you could have tested on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4668fd/1)

Answer (score 0):

You will get three rows.  The value of A will be repeated three times and each B value will be in one row.

Answer (score 0):

3 rows. Here's some text to fill in the 30char answer length requirement.